# Capturing bluetooth traffic on linux incomplete (no HID/A2DP traffic seen)

Tags: linux, bluetooth

I am attempting to capture the Bluetooth protocol being received by my computer in order to better understand how Bluetooth works. I have tried using a Bluetooth headset and a Bluetooth keyboard on Linux with tools such as tcpdump, Wireshark, and btmon.

However, in both cases, I am only able to capture packets that are low level interactions between the devices. For example, for the keyboard, I can see some ATT protocol due to Bluetooth LE, or capture the packets when connecting the device and pairing it. But the actual data packets (either HID or AD2P for the keyboard or the headset respectively) are never picked up. My computer does receive them though (otherwise my keyboard keys would never display...).

Here is an example:

```
$ sudo btmon
Bluetooth monitor ver 5.66
= Note: Linux version 5.15.114 (x86_64)                                                                                                               0.079036
= Note: Bluetooth subsystem version 2.22                                                                                                              0.079037
= New Index: AC:67:5D:49:54:2A (Primary,USB,hci0)                                                                                              [hci0] 0.079038
= Open Index: AC:67:5D:49:54:2A                                                                                                                [hci0] 0.079038
= Index Info: AC:67:5D:49:54:2A (Intel Corp.)                                                                                                  [hci0] 0.079038
@ MGMT Open: bluetoothd (privileged) version 1.21                                                                                            {0x0001} 0.079039
> ACL Data RX: Handle 3585 flags 0x02 dlen 22                                                                                               #1 [hci0] 0.194587
      ATT: Handle Value Notification (0x1b) len 17
        Handle: 0x0021
          Data: 000000000000000000000000000000
> ACL Data RX: Handle 3585 flags 0x02 dlen 8                                                                                                #2 [hci0] 2.279466
      ATT: Handle Value Notification (0x1b) len 3
        Handle: 0x0012
          Data: 51
> ACL Data RX: Handle 3585 flags 0x02 dlen 22                                                                                               #3 [hci0] 7.949616
      ATT: Handle Value Notification (0x1b) len 17
        Handle: 0x0021
          Data: 000000800000000000000000000000
```

It seems similar to trying to capture TCP/HTTP traffic, but only being able to see the SYN/ACK and TLS hello at the beginning, and then nothing.  Looking at https://www.kali.org/tools/bluez/, it seems that there are tools dedicated to specific protocols for Bluetooth, so perhaps there is no generic way to capture raw Bluetooth traffic from the computer receiving those packets in the first place. Is there a way to do this without using a different hardware to capture all Bluetooth traffic in the air?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can not. In the Host (Linux in your case), you can only see the HCI (Host Controller Interface) which is the traffic between the Bluetooth Controller and Host. If you want to see the full connection, you need to capture the traffic between Controllers with specific hardware.

In order to capture the traffic between Controllers (like LMP) you need addition hardware like Ubertooth or Ellisys Explorer.

Comment: What threw me off was the reason why: the bluetooth controller abstracts a lot of things away, while I was expecting all bluetooth traffic to be handled by Linux drivers directly, subject to updates and so on. I had in mind the OSI layer of the internet and thought for a given bluetooth protocole/profile, everything is handled like on the network.